# 405 error when using wcf with json and ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, json, wcf

I am trying to build a WCF service that accepts and returns data in json format and use it in ajax calls. The problem I am having is that when I attempt to call the WCF-service from javascript I get an 405 (Method Not Allowed)  error. It seems that the web page calls options method on the server (OPTIONS localhost:49572/Service1.svc/testmethod HTTP/1.1) to which the server responds with the 405 statuscode.

Below is my service definition

```
namespace JsonAjaxService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
       [OperationContract]
       [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(
       Method = "POST",
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
       UriTemplate = "testmethod")]
       CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
    }

[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}
```

}

And here is the Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>

  <appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
  <services>
  <service name="JsonAjaxService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
  <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="JsonAjaxService.IService1"      behaviorConfiguration="web">
  </endpoint>
  </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And finally the code I use to call this service

```
function test() {
    var json = '{"StringValue":"test","BoolValue":"false"}';
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "http://localhost:49572/Service1.svc/testmethod",
        data: json,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { alert(data); },
        error: function (data) { alert('error')); }
    });
```

Comment: Make a request using fiddler, check if it works and post headers from response. Link: http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Comment: It seems that the web page calls options method on the server (OPTIONS http://localhost:49572/Service1.svc/testmethod HTTP/1.1) to which the server responds with the 405 statuscode.

Comment: It's reasonable, as you don't have such method. If it's cross domain call (but it seems it's not), I've heard that it's required to use dataType: "jsonp". But it's definitely something wrong with JSON if you caught an Option call.

Comment: Using JSONP as datatype solved this problem but presented another. The web page performs the query using get, when wcf only accepts POST when there is a compostitetype as service method parameter.

Comment: Yes, really strange, your request seems correct. Unfortunately, can't help with this issue, as I haven't much experience with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on same domain name ? If not, use "jsonp" as dataType instead

Answer (score 0):

Think that the previous answer(about jsonp) makes sense, but if it doesn't work, try to add to "customHeaders"

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST" />
```